# Convolution filter implementation on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am implementing my convolution logic for image filtering in Python, but it is only rendering a black image every time for different input images and kernels. Need help. Below is the code

```
def convolution_filter(gray_img,kernel):
 img_ht,img_wt = gray_img.shape;
 kernel_ht, kernel_wt = kernel.shape;
 out_img = np.zeros(shape=gray_img.shape)
 k =int((kernel_ht-1)/2);

fl_kernel = kernel;
flip_code = -1;

bdr = int((kernel_wt-1)/2)
v_anchor = (kernel_ht-1)/2
gray_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray_img, bdr, bdr, bdr, bdr,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

for i in range(bdr,img_ht+bdr):
    for j in range(bdr,img_wt+bdr):
        center=gray_img[i-bdr:i+bdr+1, j-bdr:j-bdr+1]
        convolve = (center*kernel).sum()
        
        out_img[i-bdr,j-bdr] = convolve
        out_img = (out_img * 255).astype("uint8")

        
        return out_img;
```

'''

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your  `return out_img;` has the wrong alignment. Your code never does more than 1 iteration inside the loop.

Comment: I’ve updated the dupe target to a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

---

- `kernel_ht, kernel_wt = kernel.shape;`

  ---

  - Assume, my filter `[[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]` you can't use `kernel.shape`.
  - Since, the filter is 3 x 3 sized, height = `len(kernel)`, width = `len(kernel[0])`
  - ***Possible Question:*** Wait, why the width is `len(kernel[0])` what happens is `if len(kernel[1]) != len(kernel[0]) is True`?
  - ***Possible Answer***
    Mostly, the kernel's height and width are the same. But you can add:
    `kernel_wt = [len(i) for i in kernel if len(i) > len(kernel[0])]`
- `convolve = (center * kernel).sum()`

---

- The code selects only 3 variables for kernels' 9 values by default the other kernel values are multiplied with 0.
- For instance: For the first iteration the `[114, 114, 144]` pixel values are selected but we have 9 kernel values. `114 * (-1) + 114 * (0) + 114 * (-1) + 0 * -2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 2 * 0....` therefore the result is 0 and blank image
- How convolution works?

---

- [image]
- [source](https://www.kaggle.com/amarjeet007/visualize-cnn-with-keras)
- As we can see from the above gif, pseudocode will be:
- ```
  for each iteration: 
      Select 3 x 3 area
      Multiply with the kernel
      image(current_coordinates) = multiplication.
  ```
- Left input image, Right filtered image for kernel `[[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, -1, 0]]`

---

- [image] [image]
- Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def convolution_filter(gray_img, kernel):
    # temporary operation
    # gray_img = cv2.resize(gray_img, (10, 10))

    kernel_size = len(kernel)

    row = gray_img.shape[0] - kernel_size + 1
    col = gray_img.shape[1] - kernel_size + 1

    result = np.zeros(shape=(row, col))

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            current = gray_img[i:i+kernel_size, j:j+kernel_size]
            multiplication = np.abs(sum(sum(current * kernel)))
            result[i, j] = multiplication

    return result


img = cv2.imread("input.jpeg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
k = [[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, -1, 0]]

filtered = convolution_filter(gray, k)
cv2.imwrite("filtered.jpg", filtered)
```